# Geometry question about altering a square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Two opposite sides of a square are increased by $12$ cm and the other two opposite sides are decreased by $4$ cm. The newly formed rectangle has the same area as the original square. What is the length of each side of the square?

What I think will work:

$$(x+12)(x-4)=x^2$$

But I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? The more you can tell us about your thoughts and efforts, the easier it will be for us to tailor our answers to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be the side length of the square. Thus:

$$x^2=(x+12)(x-4)$$

$$x^2=x^2+8x-48$$

$$8x=48$$

$$x=6$$

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: But why is it 8x? Sorry, I'm only in grade 9, and I haven't learnt this. I don't know why it was in the homework.

Comment: When you FOIL the two factors, you get $x^2-4x+12x-48$, right? $-4x+12x=8x$. I just simplified it for you.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you again.

Comment: @Roxana My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Let the side of the square be $s$.  What is the area of the square?  What are the dimensions of the rectangle in terms of $s$?  What is the area?  Set the two areas equal and solve